# Comparing two dates PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

im trying to compare two `dates`. I want the `table` to be `editable` if the `start date` is greater than or equals to current date and `end date` is less than or equals to `current date`. Here's my scenario to explain it easily, I will set a `specific dates` for encoding of grades so if the `current date` is not in `between` of the `start` and `end` date the table will not be `editable`. Can someone help me find the cause of the problem? Is it my condition?

The data.

[image]

The code.

```
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM encode";
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
      $term = $rows['term'];
      $enddate = $rows['enddate'];
      $startdate = $rows['startdate'];
    }
   $today = date("Y-m-d"); 
   if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0){
               $output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row['middlename'].'</td>
                <td class="prelim" data-id1="'.$row['grade_id'].'" >'.$row['prelim_grade'].'</td>
                <td class="midterm" data-id2="'.$row['grade_id'].'" >'.$row['midterm_grade'].'</td>
                <td class="finals" data-id3="'.$row['grade_id'].'" >'.$row['finals_grade'].'</td>
                <td class="final" data-id4="'.$row['grade_id'].'" >'.$row['final_grade'].'</td>
                </tr>';

            }
            else{
                $output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['middlename'].'</td>';
                if($term == "Prelim" && $enddate <= $today && $startdate >= $today){
                $output .= '<td class="prelim" data-id1="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['prelim_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                $output .= '<td class="prelim" data-id1="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['prelim_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                if($term == "Midterm" && $enddate <= $today && $startdate >= $today){
                $output .= '<td class="midterm" data-id2="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['midterm_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                  $output .= '<td class="midterm" data-id2="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['midterm_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                if($term == "Finals" && $enddate <= $today && $startdate >= $today){
                  $output .= '<td class="finals" data-id3="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['finals_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                  $output .= '<td class="finals" data-id3="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['finals_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                if($term == "Final Grade" && $enddate <= $today && $startdate >= $today){
                  $output .= ' <td class="final" data-id4="'.$row['grade_id'].'" contenteditable>'.$row['final_grade'].'</td>';
                }
                else{
                  $output .= ' <td class="final" data-id4="'.$row['grade_id'].'">'.$row['final_grade'].'</td>';
                }
              $output .=' </tr>';
            }
```

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I already tried to put `strtotime` but still not working sir..

Comment: `WHERE startdate =>CURDATE()  AND enddate  <=CURDATE()`